# How to pickle and unpickle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

```
import  pickle
variety = ["sweet", "box", "cat"]
shape = ["back","spear", "log"]
pickleFile = open("pickle.txt", 'w')
pickle.dump(variety, pickleFile)
pickle.dump(shape, pickleFile)
pickleFile.close()

pickleFile = open("pickle.txt", 'r')
test = pickle.load(pickleFile)
shape = pickle.load(pickleFile)

print ("variety : ", test, " shape : ", shape)
pickleFile.close()
```

when I run above code I get the following error

```
line 6, in <module>
pickle.dump(variety, pickleFile)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

and i am not sure if unpickling in variable 'test' will be possible
or not cause I had pickled in with variable 'variety'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to `help(pickle.dump)`,

> The *file* argument must have a write() method that accepts a single
> bytes argument.  It can thus be a file object opened for binary
> writing, a io.BytesIO instance, or any other custom object that meets
> this interface.

Looks like you have to open your file in binary mode. Don't forget to do the same for `load`ing too.

```
import  pickle
variety = ["sweet", "box", "cat"]
shape = ["back","spear", "log"]
with open("file.pkl", 'wb') as picklefile:
    pickle.dump(variety, picklefile)
    pickle.dump(shape, picklefile)


with open("file.pkl", 'rb') as picklefile:
    test = pickle.load(picklefile)
    shape = pickle.load(picklefile)

print ("variety : ", test, " shape : ", shape)
```

Result:

```
variety :  ['sweet', 'box', 'cat']  shape :  ['back', 'spear', 'log']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to write a pickled object into a text file. That is like trying to write a database in MS word.

The correct file extension for a pickled file is '.pkl'. The file must also be written to and read from in binary mode.

My suggestion would be to change the file extensions to '.pkl' and then use two `with` loops to neaten up your code. The corrections to the loading and writing is as simple as changing `'w'` to `'wb'` The result looks like this:

```
import  pickle
variety = ["sweet", "box", "cat"]
shape = ["back","spear", "log"]
with open("pickle.pkl", 'wb') as pickleFile:
    pickle.dump(variety, pickleFile)
    pickle.dump(shape, pickleFile)
    pickleFile.close()

with open("pickle.pkl", 'rb') as pickleFile:
    test = pickle.load(pickleFile)
    shape = pickle.load(pickleFile)

print ("variety : ", test, " shape : ", shape)
pickleFile.close()
```